# CSS style Unicode for Left Double Quote

Tags: html, css, unicode

I want to style the Left Double Quote at the top center of my card, so it looks like a title(can be seen in pen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbWRNz)). I want it to appear bigger in size and want to learn how to style it separate from the font. Can somebody plz help?

HTML(Pug):

```
.main
  .container
    blockquote.quote Success is no accident. It is hardwork, perseverance, learning, studying, sacrifice, and most of all, love of what you are doing or learning to do.
      footer Pele
```

SCSS:

```
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: mintcream;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 height: 270px;
 width: 600px;
 background-color: tomato;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

   font-size: 24px;
}

blockquote::before{
  content: "\201C"; /*Unicode for Left Double Quote*/
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;

} 

.quote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make big quotes with <blockquote>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325687/make-big-quotes-with-blockquote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always apply basic css text styles to it, but if you want to change the appearance further (make it look different then the font's quotes), then inserting a SVG or an icon is the way to go.

Personally, I would just [search for a font](https://fonts.google.com/), where I like the left double quotes, download the font, then use a program like Inkscape to write in it, convert it to a path and change it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Add the styles to the ::before as this is the element you are adding

```
blockquote::before{
  content: "\201C"; /*Unicode for Left Double Quote*/
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color:#000; 
  font-size: 50px;
  top: -40px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the ideas! I tried something simple and it worked well for me:

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: mintcream;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 270px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: tomato;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 24px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 110px;
  margin: -30px;
  line-height: 0.6em;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.quote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <blockquote class="quote"><span>&#10077; </span>
      <p>Success is no accident. It is hardwork, perseverance, learning, studying, sacrifice, and most of all, love of what you are doing or learning to do.</p>
      <footer>Pele</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```